# How to test creation of a Rack application using cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, rack, aruba

I am creating a Ruby command line application that will generate a Rack application. I want to test that the Rack application that is created is a valid Rack application. I have started using Aruba and Cucumber to test that the CLI creates the correct files and directory structure, but now I'm ready to run `rackup` and see that the application is running correctly. How can I get Cucumber and Capybara to interact with this newly created application?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a root page for your rack application then have capybara visit whatever path you deem to be your root path and verify some sort of output on that page

```
def response
   if request.path "/" 
      Rack::Response.new(render("index.html.erb"))  
   else 
      Rack::Response.new("Not Found", 404)
    end
end
```

on rack startup: `@startup_output = "foo"`
generate some sort of output on your root page `<%= @startup_output %>`

capybara:

```
visit('/')
page.should have_content('foo')
```

If you need to have capybara start the app up try using a rake task inside the test:

```
system "rake rack:start"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a start, but I've already got a Rack application, and I'm already calling `rackup` through Aruba. I think this is different from Capybara's default behavior, so it doesn't know where to find this newly created Rack application. I think I need to tell Capybara to load the `config.ru` file, or specify the port that it's running on, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a YAML file with the configuration information (port number, path, etc) and have capybara load in that data? Then you can still use the `visit("#{CONFIG.root_url}")` in the capybara test. I recommend checking out the railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised) on YAML, it might give you some ideas. Good luck